# How to add rainbow-bridge to my own React app?

Tags: nearprotocol, aurora-evm, aurora-near, rainbow-bridge

I want to add rainbow bridge on my React JS app to allow my user to exchange tokens between  NEAR-Aurora-ETH, I found that there is a NPM package @near-eth/client, but I can't understand the docs and I am unable to add rainbow bridge on my web app.
Note:- I already added a form in my web app to send NEAR to any other near wallet but I am unable to add Rainbow-bridge.

Answer (score 0):

These are the libraries we use to interact with the bridge on rainbowbridge.app
https://github.com/aurora-is-near/rainbow-bridge-client.
This open source repo is not well maintained but it can serve as an example of how they are used in a frontend
https://github.com/aurora-is-near/rainbow-bridge-frontend.

We are also working on an embeddable bridge that can be added to websites and will have limited functionality (only deposits from Ethereum to Aurora). It will be released in the coming weeks.